# Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [*] in table [*]; found [*], but expecting [*]

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Spring Boot JPA mapping MySQL text type column, when startup console print exception.

`pom.xml`:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Brixton.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Entity:

```java
 @Column(name = "description", nullable = false, length = 65535, columnDefinition="TEXT")
    @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.StringClobType")
    private String description;
```

console info:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [description] in table [kw_product]; found [text (Types#LONGVARCHAR)], but expecting [varchar(255) (Types#VARCHAR)]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateColumnType(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateTable(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:92) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.doValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:50) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Comment: As described in the error, hibernate expected  `[varchar(255) (Types#VARCHAR)]` for `description` column but if found `[text (Types#LONGVARCHAR)]`, you have juste to change your column type in database.

Comment: I have this same error, the strange thing is that in the database my column is a "varchar(max)", but the error still says "longvarchar" was found. Isn't it wrong? Also if I specify the column definition as "VARCHAR(MAX) NULL" in the "@Column" annotation, the same error occurs except it says it expects "varchar(max)" instead of "varchar(255)".

Answer (score 2):

According to [this info](https://thorben-janssen.com/mapping-blobs-and-clobs-with-hibernate-and-jpa/) you should just replace the `@Type` annotation with `@javax.persistence.Lob` and it should work.

Comment: This lead me to the right solution for my issue. I simply used the following as my annotations  @Lob @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType") @Column(name = "description")